# ¿Tasa de refresco de PHP en una descarga masiva por FTP?

Tags: php

no se como explicar esto, pero lo intentare.

Resulta que tengo un programa que descarga muchos archivos a través de una conexión FTP.
El programa funciona bien, se demora lo que se demora en buscar, validar y descargar todos los archivos que yo le diga.

Mi tema es el sgte...
Mientras ejecuto la descarga de estos archivos, la página queda en stand by, a veces son pocos, pero durante la ejecución y descarga, estos archivos no se muestran por pantalla sino hasta que acaba de descargarlos todos, y me muestra todos los echos que le he pedido mostrarme, ej:

```
...
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/19.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/20.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/21.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/22.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/23.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/24.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/25.xml
Se ha creado el archivo C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/11111111-1/1/1/2013-01-18/26.xml
...
```

Bien, al momento de ser **MUCHOS** archivos, más de 100 por ejemplo... no se como, pero la página va cargando parcialmente estos resultados, hasta finalizar la ejecución y mostrar la última cola de resultados.
Esto me lleva a pensar, que debe haber algún modo de pedirle a la página web, que refresque la información desplegada.

Comment: creo que lo mas recomendable en este caso seria que tu app lanzara la peticion de ir descargando (por ej, en otra ventana aparte), y que por medio de ajax, se vaya recibiendo cada vez que se ha descargado un archivo y añadirlo al div correspondiente.

Comment: No soy muy entendido en ajax la verdad, pero me dices que, en otra página, podría decirle que me vaya mostrando 1 a 1 la descarga. Actualmente tengo el script, pero no se como unirlo a un ajax.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3133209/3791844).

Comment: He intentado esas soluciones que has recomendado @Marcos, pero no parecen funcionar

Comment: @Excorpion, dependiendo de la configuración de Apache, PHP, restricciones del servicio, etc. la solución puede variar. En algunos casos he tenido que imprimir `1024*64` espacios para ver la salida. Esto es porque dependiendo de ciertas configuraciones es necesario cubrir la quota (o buffer) para que el navegador las muestre

Comment: PHP dispone de un búfer que va almacenando contenido y envía al navegador hasta que se llena. Podrías intentar usando [`flush()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.flush.php) después de cada `echo` para vaciar el búfer, aunque es probable que en el servidor (apache, por ejemplo) o en el navegador también se manejen otros búfers.

Comment: @Triby eso es lo que marcos me hizo intentar, pero no parece funcionar.

Comment: Por cuestiones de optimización, algunos servidores web pueden tener configurado un búfer de salida, como [mod_buffer de Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_buffer.html) o, incluso, algún otro como [mod_deflate](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) que se puede configurar para comprimir los datos antes de enviarlos. Tal vez la mejor opción sea la sugerida por @Jakala para usar AJAX, pero sería una petición para cada archivo y podría tardar más el proceso, aunque tendrías control sobre cada uno para saber si se pudo descargar o no.

Comment: AL parecer no es rentable, dejaré entonces la petición en stand by a la espera de alguna respuesta mas simple.

Comment: ¿Aún necesitas ayuda con este tema?

Comment: Si me pudieses guiar a algo, claro que si.